# How to effectively get indices of 1s for given binary string using Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

Suppose we have a binary string such as `10010010`.

All I want is a function returning indices of `1`s for that string:

```
indicesOfOnes("10010010") -> List(0, 3, 6)
indicesOfOnes("0") -> List()
```

And what I implemented is:

```
def indicesOfOnes(bs: String): List[Int] = {
  val lb = ListBuffer[Int]()
  bs.zipWithIndex.foreach { case (v, i) =>
    if (v == '1') {
      lb += i
    }
  }
  lb.toList
}
```

This works, but I think there're much better (more functional) ways to do this job. Any advices would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a `filter` and then `map` to get the index :

```
scala> val s = "10010010"
s: String = 10010010

scala> s.zipWithIndex.withFilter(_._1 == '1').map(_._2)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(0, 3, 6)
```

Note: I'm using `withFilter` and not `filter` to avoid creating a temporary collection.

---

Or you can use `collect`, which applies a partial function on the elements over which it is defined:

```
scala> s.zipWithIndex.collect { case (char, index) if char == '1' => index }
res2: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(0, 3, 6)
```